# Android - Wrong view using on touch event

Tags: android, events, touch-event

I want to create an Android application to control a car remotely using wifi.
I discovered something pretty weird about ontouch events, if I keep touching the screen, event if I touch another button the event will call the first view, because I don't release the screen.

So, if I touch the FORWARD button, if I try to go left/right at the same time, I can't, because the event called is always forward if I don't relase the button. I have to stop touch the screen and touch left/right button to change direction.

How can I manage that?
Thank you.

```
// On click, go forward.
        this.goForwardBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goForward();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when your `Activity` implements `onTouchListener`. You can define a view that does not cover the entire screen and let it implement onTouchListener.

Comment: Actually, my Activity doesn't implement onTouchListener but I think it's the same with my way: I updated the main post.

Comment: All the source code is available here: https://github.com/Vadorequest/AAD1/tree/master/Android

Comment: XML: https://github.com/Vadorequest/AAD1/blob/master/Android/res/layout/activity_car.xml

Comment: Activity: https://github.com/Vadorequest/AAD1/blob/master/Android/src/com/iha/wcc/CarActivity.java

Comment: I am facing the same exact problem but i can't understand how this was solved.

Comment: My explanation is when the Activity is a listener, it listens to touch event on entire screen. A view that is a listener only listen to events that are within the view.

Comment: I undesrtand this but i do not have an activity as a listener. I have 4 custom views in a LinearLayout and every view implements its own onTouchEvent and, when a finger is kept pressed on view 1 all subsequent events, even if started on other views, are sent to view 1. Everything works fine if i use only 1 finger.

Comment: SOLVED: my problem is caused by targetSdk=10. I am using it because my app is fullscreen and i want to show the soft menu button and setting targetSdk above 10 causes it to not show.... this is another problem tough